example for wrapper-class in c++20 using constructible_from concept
I wish to create a class that behaves like the class it is wrapping around. what I get is a compile error when I try stuff like this:
#include<vector>
#include<concepts>

template<class C1>
struct wrapper{
    C1 p1;
    wrapper():p1(){}
    wrapper(wrapper&& o): p1(std::move(o.p1)){}
    ~wrapper(){p1.~C1();}
    template<class ...C>
    wrapper(C... c)requires std::constructible_from<C1,C...>:p1(std::forward<C>(c)...){}
};
//using namespace set_model;
int main() {
    using w=wrapper<std::vector<float>>;
    w a(5,1.2);
    w b{std::vector<float>{1.2,1.7,1.9}};
    //w c{1.2,1.7,1.9}; error:no matching constructor
    //w d{{1.2,1.7,1.9}}; error:no matching constructor
    std::vector<float> e{{1.2,1.7,1.9}};
    return 0
}

the constructors found in the sourcecode seems to work here, but not initializer_list! any idea how I can make wrapper behave exactly like the class it wraps, in this case std::vector? in b it can be seen that vector is initialized by a list in curly brackets, in e also curly brackets inside curly brackets is accepted. however same for wrapper class will not work. do I need to provide an initializer_list constructor? why does the default-constructed one fail the requirement?

A {} enclosed thing is not an expression.  It has no type.
{} enclosed lists of expressions can be used to initialize things, but they themselves cannot be used to deduce the type of something.
C++ does not support perfect wrapping.  You can get closer if you do a few changes
template<class C1>
struct wrapper{
  C1 p1;

  wrapper() = default;
  wrapper& operator=(wrapper&& o)& = default;
  wrapper& operator=(wrapper const& o)& = default;
  wrapper(wrapper&& o) = default;
  wrapper(wrapper const& o) = default;
  ~wrapper() = default;

  template<class ...Cs>
  wrapper(Cs&&... cs)
    requires std::constructible_from<C1,Cs...>
  :
    p1(std::forward<Cs>(cs)...)
  {}

  template<class Is, class ...Cs>
  wrapper(std::initializer_list<Is> il, Cs&&... cs)
    requires std::constructible_from<C1,std::initializer_list<Is>, Cs...>
  :
    p1(il, std::forward<Cs>(cs)...)
  {}
};

here I fixed your buggy destructor and made your special member functions all =default.
As wrapper<blah> has a std::initializer_list ctor (even a template one), your {} now tries to match it (and succeeds).
